# Decorators in Python. How to check args type

Tags: python, decorator

```
def args_typecheck(func):    
    def wrapper(type):
        def inner(*args):
            if not all(map(lambda x: isinstance(x, type), args)):
                raise TypeError
            return func(*args)
        return inner
    return wrapper

@args_typecheck(str)
def seq(*args):
    return reduce(operator.eq, args)
```

I try to check input arguments type by using decorators. But it does not work.

Error:

> if not all(map(lambda x: isinstance(x, type), args)): E   TypeError:
>   isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your decorator function signatures are reversed: `wrapper` should take the original wrapped function, and `args_typecheck` should take the type to check:

```
def args_typecheck(type):
   def wrapper(func):
      def inner(*args):
        if not all(map(lambda x: isinstance(x, type), args)):
            raise TypeError
        return func(*args)
      return inner
   return wrapper

@args_typecheck(str)
def seq(*args):
  return reduce(operator.eq, args)
```